# Center of lamina

Tags: geometry, centroid

Here is example of some planar lamina; non-convex, but without self-intersections.
I'd like to define some "my" center of lamina that will be always and only **inside it**.
Is it possible to do it correctly?

[image]

For instance there are two well-known centers:
1. Point that minimizes the sum of squared Euclidean distances between itself 
and each point in the set - mass center.
2. Point that minimizes the sum of Euclidean distances - median.

With Mathematica we can find points that minimize the sum of some other distances -   [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (point 3) etc.
But I just wish to find a centroid close to red point.
Is it possible to do it correctly and analytically?

Comment: Now I see that Manhattan distance *depends on the rotation of the coordinate system*.
A "good" center should be not, of course.

Comment: Perhaps something like a mass center only constrained to points of the figure (from all the available points pick the one that minimizes the sum of squares of distances or inside-distances)?

Comment: Thank you, but no, I tried it. Such center is a point of a boundary of lamina, closest to mass center. In the example there are two such points, so algorithm switch between them. And this is not what I think about.

Comment: What about the shortest-path distances, i.e. the whole path has to be inside? (I assume you don't have holes.)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of [dtldarek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26306/dtldarek) about inside paths was a really good proposal.
And the only way  I see for to find such paths is c*overing of lamina with some network graph*.
There are many methods and software for exploring it.

"Mathematica" has a lot of graph functions, so I spent some time conducting experiments.
We may choose any suitable network, but we must make a *weights for edges* with [Bray–Curtis dissimilarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bray%E2%80%93Curtis_dissimilarity).
Than we can find a center that minimized sum of graph distances to other points.

Only this method gives results looking realistically to me for any areas:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Why Bray–Curtis? I don't know.